# string vs symbols rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I got stuck with an error for days in my rspec tests. Then i found that the problem was the use of symbol instead of string

```
user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbilize_names: true)
expect(user_response[:email]).to eql(@user.email)
```

The above code always fails since `user_response[:email]` returns `nil` for some reasons

But when i change it to `user_responce['email']` the test passed

Debugging with byebug to check the value of user_response

```
(byebyg) user_response
{"id"=>1, "email"=>"enola@bauch.ca", "created_at"=>"2017-08-30T14:22:43.597Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-08-30T14:22:43.597Z"}
```

What is the difference between using symbol and string in the case above?

Comment: You have a typo: `symbilize_names` should be `symbolize_names`

Comment: (and `JSON.parse` should raise an `ArgumentError` therefore, but that's a different story)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a Hash in Ruby, any object such a string or a symbol can be used as the key. However, `:email` and `"email"` are different objects so to look up an object you must use the same object that was used to store the value.

What might be confusing you is that Rails uses a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` in some places. This is a customised hash where keys `:foo` and `"foo"` are considered to be the same. This allows you to use e.g. `params[:user]` and `params["user"]` interchangeably, however that is not the general case.

As [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) spotted, the reason why strings were being used for the keys in the parsed JSON object was just down to a small typo in the option: `symbilize_names` where it should be `symbolize_names`.

Answer (score 5):

This really has nothing to do with symbols or strings per se. You have a hash. That hash contains a value for the key `'email'`. It doesn't contain a value for the key `'foobar'` or `42` or `:hello` or `[1, 2, 3]` or `:email`. Ergo, if you ask it for the value of one of those, you get the default value, which is `nil` by default.

This is not about symbols or strings. You are simply asking the hash for the value of a non-existent key. There is no key `:email` in the hash, ergo you get the default value.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols and strings are simply different types of objects. Same as `'5'` and `5` are different. They superficially *look* similar, but actually they are not related.

> What is the difference between using symbol and string in the case above?

In your case, your data structure contained string keys and didn't contain symbol keys. Simple as that.